# Which attach to process should I choose for visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm not sure which one should I pick.

[image]

Comment: Use Task Manager to help you find the process you want, get its process ID, then attach the debugger to that process ID.

Comment: I am sorry but what am I actually doing here? I actually don't even know what process I want

Comment: Bub, if you don't know, we're kind of stuck. Why do you think you need to attach to a process? Are you debugging a plug-in? A library? Help us help you by providing more information.

Comment: Sure, the lecturer just sent couple of cpp files, which was made in eclipse previously, to the course website. So I tried to open it by visual studio.

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask your lecturer for clarification. If you don't know what you want to do, then we can't help you to do it.

Comment: Recommendation: Try to make your build environment  as close to the same as your instructor as possible. While this will lead you to other problems, such as the instructor using code that exploits the foibles of a particular compiler and accidentally fooling you into thinking that they are actually Standard features, you will get fewer surprises. For example you could use non-Standard features of your compiler in an assignment  and get a low mark when your code won't compile on the marker's PC.

Comment: The right way is to write 100% Standard-compliant code and make sure the marker is compiling against the same Standard. It's also worth it to have a collection of compilers to run your code against. A Syntax error may have a much more understandable message in one compiler than another. A logic error that one compiler ignores, another might flag for you. The differences in how different compilers interpreted the code may expose different errors at runtime.

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes as it does not give enough details about your question.

Comment: The picture explains just about everything, and frankly I don't know how someone unfamiliar with build tools, specifically Visual Studio, could have explained it without the picture. Anyone who knew enough to describe the problem in text would probably know the solution. On the other hand, the picture makes the question unsearchable and of limited use to future askers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is trying to find an instance of the program that matches the cpp file you opened to debug the program. Not what you want to do.

You need to create a Visual Studio project to manage the program you're going to build. Select *File->New->Project*

From the Dialog that brings up, Track down and expand *Visual C++* in the tree structure on the left. Look for and select *Win32*. Click *Win32 Console Project* from the pane in the middle. Name the project appropriately and place it somewhere on the hard drive where you can find it easily later. Click *OK*.

Now you get the Application Wizard. Click *Next*. Uncheck *Precompiled Header*. You probably don't care about the SDL checks either, but they won't give you the kinds of grief the Precompiled Headers will at this stage of your career. I don't think anyone really knows why Precompiled Headers are on by default, but by the time you need them, you know what they are and how to take advantage of them. A one file program doesn't need them and leaving them on will give you a bunch of errors. Click *Finish*.

Select all of the code in the editor. Paste the code provided by the instructor over top of it.

To build and run the program click the green Play button.